# How do I change the hostname on Ubuntu Touch?

Tags: networking, ubuntu-touch

I got my 2nd Ubuntu Touch device this week, the BQ tablet. I already have an Ubuntu phone and for both devices the hostname is "ubuntu-phablet" so I'd like to change at least one of the two.

I have tried changing the tablet's hostname by remounting the filesystem read-write and issuing a new name with the 'hostname' command but the new name didn't stay after a reboot. What am I missing?

Comment: Have you tried editing /etc/hosts while in read-write mode rather than using the host name command ?

Comment: Added a bug to track this. https://bugs.launchpad.net/canonical-devices-system-image/+bug/1574370

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out I needed to edit the file /etc/hostname (and update the ::1 and 127.0.1.1 entries in /etc/hosts). Rebooted and everything is fine.

Comment: That doesn't work without remounting the filesystem as read/write though (with all the possible implications that has).

Comment: Indeed it doesn't. First thing I did afterwards was reboot to make sure it was set to read-only again.